# Simplifying $(m^3)^4(2x^3)^7(m^2)^5(3x)^2$

Tags: problem-solving

I am having trouble with simplifying the following algebraic expression:

$$(m^3)^4(2x^3)^7(m^2)^5(3x)^2$$

I have been able to do the exponents and all the other equations I needed to simplify but not this one. If somebody could provide a step by step solution to the equation then that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $(n^a)^b=n^{ab}$ and $(n^a)(n^b)=n^{a+b}$

Comment: where is "equation."

Comment: You want to call this an "expression". Equations have equal signs.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so you want to simplify
$$
(m^3)^4(2x^3)^7(m^2)^5(3x)^2
$$
As the other answer attempts to, you can focus on each factor on its own. You simply use the rules that

- $x^ax^b = x^{a+b}$ and
- $(x^a)^b = x^{ab}$ and
- $(xy)^{a} = x^ay^a$

So
$$
\begin{align}
(m^3)^4 &= m^{3\cdot 4} = m^{12} \\
(2x^3)^7 &= 2^7(x^3)^7 = 2^7x^{21}\\
(m^2)^5 &= m^{10}\\
(3x)^2 &= 3^2x^2
\end{align}
$$
So
$$\begin{align}
(m^3)^4(2x^3)^7(m^2)^5(3x)^2 
&= m^{12}2^7x^{21}m^{10}3^2x^2 \\
&= 2^73^2m^{12}m^{10}x^{21}x^{2} \\
&= 2^73^2m^{22}x^{23}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: It's not (m^3)^2 but instead (m^3)^4. And the calculator is giving me an answer of 128x^21 for (2x^3)^7.

Comment: @Anonymous: I already fixed that :)

Comment: The calculator is giving me an answer of 1152m^22x^23.

Comment: @Anonymous: Well, what is $2^7$ times $3^2$?

Comment: Isn't (2x^3)^7 equal to 128^21?

Comment: @Anonymous: Nope. $(\color{red}{2}\color{green}{x^3})^7 = \color{red}{2}^7(\color{green}{x^3})^7$ because of the rule $(\color{red}{x}\color{green}{y})^n = \color{red}{x}^n\color{green}{y}^n$

Comment: I don't get it.

Comment: @Anonymous: Consider this example $6^3 = 216$. And since $6 = 2\cdot 3$ you could also do $(2\cdot3)^3 = 2^3\cdot3^3 = 8\cdot 27$ which is still $216$.

Comment: Interesting. But what about (2x^3)^7=2x^3*2x^3*2x^3*2x^3^2x^3*2x^3*2x^3?

Comment: @Anonymous: Exactly, so you will have $7$ factors of $2$ and $7$ factors of $x^3$.

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct answer?

Comment: @Anonymous: I am pretty sure.